# Showing only first and single record from database in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get all record which are available in my database table currently there are 3 records available with id 1,2 and 3 and i am only getting record related to id 1.

My Controller method:

```
 public function EmailList()
{
    $listing = Buyer::all();
    return view('email-list',compact('listing'));
}
```

and my route:

```
$router->get('/List-of-Emails', 'AjaxController@EmailList');
```

and in my view i am passing foreach loop

```
                       @foreach($listing as $list)
                            <tr>

                                <input type="hidden" id="rwid" value="{{$list->id}}"/>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="{{$list->id}}" class="checkbox-custom" name="{{$list->id}}" type="checkbox"
                                           value="{{$list->id}}">
                                    <label for="{{$list->id}}" class="checkbox-custom-label"></label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Tolltip">
                                        {{$list->name}}
                                    </p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="" class="pglst-lnk">
                                        {{$list->email}}
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{$list->created_at}}
                                </td>
                                <td>

                                </td>


                            </tr>


                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                    </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>
@endforeach
```

i am getting only first and only single record however i want to get all records from table where i am doing wrong.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(),

Comment: if i follow your logic it says

Comment: Show your complete view file. You have attached it seems half view file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a DOM parsing error.

Can you put the `@endforeach` just below the closing `</tr>` tag?

```
@foreach($listing as $list)
    <tr>
        <!-- data -->
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

**EDIT: Explanation**

For those interested: the browser is incapable of parsing the HTML as given by OP. This is because after one record, he closes the table and a couple of divs. Then the foreach-loop starts again, in which he suddenly introduces new `<tr>`s and is closing `<table>`s and `<div>`s that don't exist. It will probably put an error message in the console, but not everybody looks there as it's not directly obvious that the outputted HTML is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use Some query like

```
  $user = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->orderby('id','desc')->limit('the record you want')->first();
```